# Simple expect else script

Tags: if-statement, expect

I was trying to run a command and expect an output and I have that ready to go but I just can't seem to get the correct syntax for what to do if I don't get that expected output.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn ./container_check
expect -- "*wpa_supplicant-udmpro:v1.0*"
send -- "exit\r"
else -- "podman container start wpa_supplicant-udmpro\r"
expect eof
```

I want the script to exit if it sees the wpa_supplicant response but I also want it to run "podman container start wpa_supplicant-udmpro" if it doesn't and I can't seem to get it to do that.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn ./container_check
if [ expect "*wpa_supplicant-udmpro:v1.0*" ];
    then { send "exit\r"; }
else { send "podman container start wpa_supplicant-udmpro\r"; }
expect eof
fi
```

Another attempt, I have no idea what I am doing LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I have a feeling that the "podman" command should be sent to the OS, not to the "container_check" program. If true, then perhaps this is all you need:</strike>

If "container_check" exits non-zero or emits anything to stderr, `exec` will error and that needs to be caught:

```tcl
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
if {[catch {exec ./container_check 2>@1} check_output] != 0} {
    # a non-zero exit status: do we care?
}
if {![string match "*wpa_supplicant-udmpro:v1.0*" $check_output]} {
    exec podman container start wpa_supplicant-udmpro
}
```

ref: [exec](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm), [string](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm)

If the `container_check` program really does require interaction, then I'm wrong.

---

Since you're using sshpass, you have no need to interact with the ssh process: expect is the wrong tool for this job. Stick with a simple bash script.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
doSsh() {
    sshpass -p "password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@ipaddress "$@"
}

if [[ "$( doSsh docker container ls )" != *"wpa_supplicant-udmpro:v1.0"* ]]; then
    doSsh podman container start wpa_supplicant-udmpro
fi
```

Comment: it is erroring out on the ./container_check now which is just a ssh command to connect to the other server and run a command that lists all running pods

Comment: while executing
"exec ./container_check"
    invoked from within
"set check_output [exec ./container_check]"
    (file "./expect" line 2)

Comment: What's the full error message? You've omitted the important bit before "while executing"

Comment: It doesn't require interaction but I am using the output from it's command to make the decision on which command to run.

Comment: that is the only output I get when running the command here is the contents of container_check

Comment: sshpass -p "password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@ipaddress docker container ls

Comment: I presume that the "podman" command also needs to run via ssh?\

Comment: correct btw your new code runs fine when the string is matched "the container is running" but if it isn't matched then it thows this error

Comment: couldn't execute "podman": no such file or directory
    while executing
"exec podman container start wpa_supplicant-udmpro"
    invoked from within
"if {![string match "*wpa_supplicant-udmpro:v1.0*" $check_output]} {
    exec podman container start wpa_supplicant-udmpro
}"
    (file "./expect" line 5)

Comment: not familiar with doSsh is that something i can get from apt-get?

Comment: It's just a function defined within the script. Merely so you only need to hardcode the password, etc, in one place.